# Parameterized function for connect

Tags: pyqt

I have assigned one method to combobox like this

```
def run(self):
    GetAllLayers(self) #custom Methods
    #attach index changed event / passing parametric method
    self.dlg.cbLayerNamesAll.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda arg=self:  LayersValueChange(arg))
```

getting error here

```
def LayersValueChange(self):      
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()//here error
```

And Error is:

> layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
>   AttributeError:
>   'int' object has no attribute 'iface'

self is object but it getting it like int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `LayersValueChange` is an *external function* and not a method of the same class, you can connect the signal like this:

```
    self.dlg.cbLayerNamesAll.currentIndexChanged.connect(
        lambda: LayersValueChange(self))
```

This simply ignores the parameters sent by the signal, and creates a function enclosure that allows `self` to be referenced later (so there's no need to use `arg=self`).

If you also want the index sent by the signal, you will have to change the signature of the function, and then connect the signal like this:

```
    self.dlg.cbLayerNamesAll.currentIndexChanged.connect(
        lambda index: LayersValueChange(self, index))

def LayersValueChange(self, index):      
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    print(index)
```

However, a much better design would be to make all the functions methods of the same class. Then your code would look like this:

```
class MyClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(parent)
        ...
        self.dlg.cbLayerNamesAll.currentIndexChanged.connect(
            self.layersValueChange)

    def run(self):
        self.getAllLayers()

    def layersValueChange(self, index):
        layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()

    def getAllLayers(self):
        ...
```

Comment: All my confused thoughts formulated in a coherent answer. +1

Comment: @ekhumoro why some time my event run twice or more. while acutally LayersValueChange is in the same class. it is a function that i want to run on combox box index change.

Comment: `currentIndexChanged` is emitted every time the index changes through the user interface or programmatically. It might be that somewhere in your code you change the index, causing the signal to fire again. 
If you don’t want the signal to fire for an index change, you can block it like this: `self.dlg.cbLayerNamesAll.blockSignals(True) some index changing code self.dlg.cbLayerNamesAll.blockSignals(False)`

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan. Does your program call `run()` more than once? If so, the `currentIndexChanged` signal would be sent for *every connection that is made*. To fix this, do the connection *only once*, e.g. in `__init__` (or wherever you create `self.dlg`). I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The whole signature of your signal is: `currentIndexChanged(int index)` (see [the doc](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged)). So the argument, your lambda is receiving is of type `int` and from that information Python assumes the `self` parameter of your `LayersValueChanged` is of type `int`.

You need to do two things:

1. Don’t pass self as default parameter. In fact you don’t need any default parameter, because `currentIndexChanged` always provides one.
2. Change your slot signature to correctly accept the int parameter:

   ```
   def LayersValueChange(self, index): 
       …
   ```

Comment: But note that in the example code, `GetAllLayers` and `LayersValueChange` are being called as ordinary functions, not instance methods. So it really is necessary to explicitly pass `self` to them. The simplest solution would therefore be to make the signal connection like this: `connect(lambda: LayersValueChange(self))`. Of course, this looks like a lousy design - but maybe the OP has a good reason for doing things this way (unlikely, but you never know).

Comment: Yes this was my problem too when reading the question. My assumption is that those functions were meant to be called as instance methods. Maybe you can elaborate on that a little @MohammadFaizanKhan

Comment: @xsquared so how to add these two paramenters here during event assignment self.dlg.cbLayerNamesAll.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda arg=self:  LayersValueChange(arg))

Comment: Is `LayersValueChange()` in the same class as `run()`? Why aren’t you calling it as instance method? Maybe this is, what you actually want? `lambda arg:  self.LayersValueChange(arg)` and `def LayersValueChange(self, index):`

Comment: LayersValueChange is the method in the same class where run event is present. I just want to register  LayersValueChange () as an event of combobox index change. That it. Now u said that i call it like instance method. i dont want to call it i want to register it.

Comment: sorry I am new to python